# Escaping out templating with php

Tags: php, variables, smarty, output, templating

Is there a way to mix html and php variables easily? This is the kind of thing I am trying to do:

```
<p><strong>Organisation Name:</strong> {$_SESSION['org-name']}</p>
```

Is this possible without using a templating engine for PHP like `Smarty`?

Comment: And why don't you want the templating engine?

Comment: just don't want to add more code. Thought there may be new php 5.3+ way to do it.

Comment: As of php version 5.4 you can do `<?= $_SESSION['org-name']; ?>` without any changes to the config

Comment: looks good but not running 5.4 - if I was to use an engine what is neatest/most lightweight one. http://www.raintpl.com/ looks ok?

Comment: @ciclismo you can use this also in 5.3 but you will need to enable shorttags in your configuration of php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest possible solution I can think of is using the php shorttag, and some kind of MVC (or at least VC) structure:

**view.php**

```
<div>
My name is <?= $myName ?>
</div>
```

**main.php**

```
$myName = 'John'; //or $_SESSION['myName'] or whatever
include 'view.php'; // after include the variable $myName will be visible inside of view.php
```